# Angular 6 @Viewchild is not working with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, lazy-loading

Here is my code that gives error cannot read property title undefined.

Parent Component

```
import { Child } from './child.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
})
export class ParentComponet implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 constructor(){}

  @ViewChild(Child) child: Child;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("check data", this.child.title)
  }
}
```

And Child Component is.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'child',
    })
    export class ChildComponet {

     public title = "hi"
     constructor(){}

    }
```

routing.module.ts is like

```
{
        path: "",
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/child',
                component: ChildComponent
            }
        ]
}
```

And Gives error is

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined(…)
```

Comment: can you share your parent.component.html file ?

Comment: Try with something like this... In your parent.component html: `<child #myChildComponent></child>` and in your parent component typescript: `@ViewChild('myChildComponent') child: Child;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are missing **'template' or 'templateUrl'** in relevance to creating a Component

**ParentComponent**

```
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';    // {ChildComponent} not {Child} as we are referencing it to the exported class of ChildComponent

@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `<child></child>`
})
export class ParentComponet implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {...}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>`
})
export class ChildComponent {...}       // Be sure to spell it right as yours were ChildComponet - missing 'n'
```

---

**UPDATE** as per the user's clarification on this thread

Had added a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-router-outlet-activate) for your reference *(Check the console)*

If you want to access the ChildComponent that is rendered under the Parent Component's `<router-outlet>` you can do so by utilizing **(activate) supported property of router-outlet**:

> A router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component is being instantiated
>
> [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

**ParentComponent's Template**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   template: `<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

    onActivate(event): void {
        console.log(event);         // Sample Output when you visit ChildComponent url
                                    // ChildComponent {title: "hi"}

        console.log(event.title);   // 'hi' 
    }

}
```

> The result will differ based on the visited page **under your parent's children**
>
> If you visit **Child1Component** you will get its instance `Child1Component {title: "hi"}`
>
> If you visit **Child2Component** you will get its instance `Child2Component {name: "Angular"}`
>
> **These results will then be reflected on your ParentComponent's onActivate(event) console for you to access**

Comment: Hiii @KShewengger...thanks for your time....Actually I have multiple child components so I am useing <router-outlet></router-outlet> to render child view..

Comment: Hi @Ricky had updated my answer :)
Since you can't use @ViewChild() on your ParentComponent since your ChildComponent is not a direct descendant or physically included on your Parent Component's Template. So the workaround, since you are loading them on your router-outlet, why not try to use its (activate) supported property of router-outlet

Answer (score 3):

That's not how it's supposed to work. You'll be only able to get the `ChildComponent` in your `ParentComponent` **ONLY** if you have the `<app-child></app-child>` tag in your `ParentComponent` Template.

Something like this:

```
...

<app-child></app-child>

...
```

But since you're using child routing, and the `ChildComponent` will load on the `router-outlet` of your `ParentComponent` you won't have access to that using `ViewChild`

**PS:** You'll only have access to it inside `ngAfterViewInit` as `ViewChild` can only be considered safe to have instantiated after the View has loaded:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';
...

@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.childComponent);
  }

}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jghnlc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.html) for your ref that illustrates your scenario in both the cases.

**PS:** To get the `ChildComponent` properties in your `ParentComponent`, with Routing, you'll have to either use a `SharedService` or you'll have to pass the ChildProperty in the route as a QueryParam and read it in your ParentComponent using the `ActivatedRoute`

### UPDATE:

#### Sharing Data using Route Query Params:

Although this won't make much sense, but in your `ChildComponent`, you can have a Link that would route the user to the ChildComponent with the `title` property passed as a `queryParam`. Something like this:

```
<a 
  [routerLink]="['/child']" 
  [queryParams]="{title: title}">
  Go To Child Route With Query Params
</a>
```

And in your `ParentComponent` have access to it using `ActivatedRoute` like this:

```
...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
      console.log('queryParams[`title`]', queryParams['title']);
    });
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

#### Using a `SharedService`

Just create a `SharedService` with a `private` `BehaviorSubject` that would be exposed as an `Observable` by calling the `asObservable` method on it. It's value can be set by exposing a method(`setChildProperty`) that will essentially call the `next` method with the updated `childProperty` value :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private childProperty: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  childProperty$: Observable<string> = this.childProperty.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setChildProperty(childProperty) {
    this.childProperty.next(childProperty);
  }

}
```

You can then inject it both in your `ParentComponent` and in your `ChildComponent`:

In `ChildComponent` set the value:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  public title = "hi"

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.setChildProperty(this.title);
  }

}
```

And in your `ParentComponent` get the value:

```
...
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  constructor(
    ...,
    private sharedService: SharedService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.sharedService.childProperty$.subscribe(
      childProperty => console.log('Got the Child Property from the Shared Service as: ', childProperty)
    );
  }

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure inside your `parent.component.html` template you've added the `<child></child>` tag.

Comment: Hiii @Morema...thanks for your time....Actually I have multiple child components so I am using <router-outlet></router-outlet> to render child view..

Comment: No worries, just trying to help and learn along the way. @KShewengger explained intelligently in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627847/3640214) and I also got to learn :)